# How to catch connection error on Perl MongoDB driver?

Tags: mongodb, perl

I'm using an [official Perl driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB) for working with mongodb. To catch and handle errors, `Try::Tiny` and `Safe::Isa` modules are [recommended](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Error#USAGE). However, it doesn't work as expected. Please check code below that should work according to documentation but in fact it doesn't work:

```
use MongoDB;
use Try::Tiny;
use Safe::Isa;

my $client;

try {
    $client = MongoDB->connect('mongodb://localhost');
    $client->connect;
} catch {
    warn "caught error: $_";
};

my $collection = $client->ns('foo.bar');

try {
  my $all = $collection->find;
} catch {
  warn "2 - caught error: $_";;
};
```

As far as connections are established automatically according documentation there will be no exception on `connect()`. But there is no exception on request too! Also I added `$client->connect` string to [force](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient#connect) connection, but again no exception. I'm running this script at machine where there is no mongodb installed and no mongodb docker container running so an exception definitely must appear.

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `connect` doesn't throw exception, so you have nothing to catch.. `perl -MMongoDB -E 'say $client = MongoDB->connect("mongodb://nosuchhost");say $client->ns("foo.bar")->find'`

Comment: output is
```MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x3af37c8)
MongoDB::Cursor=HASH(0x3590010)``` as you see, no MongoDB::Error object

Comment: You can remove all those `try`/`catch` blocks. The code simply doesn't throw an exception; it thinks everything's fine even if there is no mongo server. Apparently this isn't an error.

Comment: Confirmed on OS X with no Mongo DB. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: Created an issue in official bugtracker, awaiting review https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PERL-771

Answer (score 1):

This is a subtle issue.  `find` returns a cursor object but doesn't issue the query immediately.  From the documentation for [MongoDB::Collection](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Collection#find):

```
Note, a MongoDB::Cursor object holds the query and does not issue the
query to the server until the `result` method is called on it or until
an iterator method like `next` is called.
```